# BottomSheet focus issue

Tags: android, google-maps, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

I have used BottomSheet in Android which contains a MapView inside it and an EditText to search data.

Now, Map and BottomSheet behavior working fine until SoftKeyboard is not open, i.e. Map scrolling like charm.

The **Issue** is that When SoftKeyboard is open and I am trying to scroll map from top to bottom with some hard scroll, BottomSheet getting closed(state to hidden) which is not in the case when SofKeyboard is not open.

What might be the solution to avoid BottomSheet to get closed when scrolling the map to down **while, SofeKeyboard is open.**

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The layout which contains BottomSheet is as below which has TabLayout and it contains Three Fragments in it and map is in first fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rltBottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_10"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/view_pager_bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/view_bottom_sheet_bg" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rltHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgBackAll"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_10"
                    android:padding="@dimen/size_15"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_back_all" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_10"
                    android:padding="@dimen/size_5"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_gym" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator_color"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/size_2"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/explore_tab_text_color"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/explore_tab_text_color" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/vp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_bottom_overlay"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout

Comment: ok let me edit..

Comment: @ADM added main fragment which has BottomSheet, inside viewpager replacing fragment which contains map.

Comment: Does your view_bottom_sheet_bg contain `NestedScrollView`? If not try after adding .

Comment: It contains ScrollView instead of Nested...

Comment: Make it Nested and then check .

Comment: @ADM Done. NestedScrollView solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Well played .. Thx

Comment: What about putting clusters above the ==>Current location circle on Googlemap ? Since am using Clustering my clusters coming back of current location circle and due to it, cluster on current location is hiding back of current location circle. Note : I know this should be new question. ;)

Comment: This should be new question i guess need more explanation . With images .

Comment: you can go through : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666144/cluster-markers-overlay-by-users-current-location-icon-in-android/42869111 and i dont want to use custom circle marker. thanks.

Comment: I have gone thorough this link . But did not get much . You probably post a new question  it will show in newest queue and someone will answer. Pls Accept my  answer below as its helped you .Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your root of `MapView` as `NestedScrollView`.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    // Your content goes here
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: After accepted answer this question can be use in marking (duplicate of ) . Thats why i asked for.Thx