# Drawing the Current_Location Marker(circle) before the cluster markers on Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, cluster-computing, marker

I am using Clustering on google map.
I have set current location circle on google map using below lines :

```
mMapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

The issue is that, current location circle is overlapping the cluster.
Is there any way to put the current location marker to back of cluster count ?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, you can create custom Current Location Marker (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33417474/6950238)) and place it under the cluster markers on Google Map.

Comment: Actually, I have created it. But, the issue is that When, Cluster it above that custom marker it doesn't taking click of cluster. it taking click of Marker. Instead, I want signle click of Cluster. Which i can achive with default current location marker of google map.